# Source of shloka "Satkarmabhischa satphalitham..."

Tags: shloka, reference-request

Please tell me the source of this verse. I had heard that in a movie song. It seemed like a sloka:

> Satkarmabhischa satphalitham
> Dushkarma yepa dushphalam
> Achyutkata punya paapanaam
> Satyam paraani bhapamiham

Comment: Which movie is this? Is it on YouTube? Can you add the link?

Comment: https://youtu.be/5AfVNTSWr-I  it is from a telugu movie "bluffmaster"